# Hosted PHP application :: Error in Stripe Payment integration

Tags: php, hosting, stripe-payments, payment

I have hosted my PHP application and everything is working fine except for the Stripe Payment integration in it.

Can someone suggest what could be the error?

```
require_once('../../Stripe/init.php');

\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_************');

$e="";

// Get the credit card details submitted by the form
$token = $_POST['stripeToken'];

// Create the charge on Stripe's servers - this will charge the user's card
try {
    $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
        "amount" => $stripe_amount, // amount in cents, again
        "currency" => "cad",
        "source" => $token,
        "description" => "Buy Gift Card"
    ));
} catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
    $e = "Your card has been declined, please enter a valid card";
}
```

It's working fine on my local machine, but on my hosting it gives me this error:

> 500 - Internal server error. There is a problem with the resource you
>   are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

Comment: So what is the error? I'm not in a guessing mood today haha

Comment: 500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

Comment: Check your error logs and post the most recent entries in relation to this!

Comment: 2016-05-24 21:18:54 W3SVC2398 JASMINE 143.95.251.7 GET /Views/GiftCards/Script/index.js - 80 - Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/+Safari/537.36 http://onlineshop.akshigakhar.com/Views/GiftCards/Views/message_form.php onlineshop.akshigakhar.com W3SVC2398 JASMINE  POST /Views/GiftCards/Views/thankyougift.php - 80Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/50.0.2661.102+Safari/537.36 http://onlineshop.akshigakhar.com/Views/GiftCards/Views/message_form.php onlineshop.akshigakhar.com 500

Comment: Sorry - your php error logs. (not access log)

Comment: Where can i find that?

Comment: added spacing in code - fixed minor grammar/typos - added quote tags to error message